# Convert JSON array into another structure

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am looking for a solution where I can convert the JSON structure with C#. Currently, I am trying to convert this JSON structure using the Newtonsoft library but I'm not finding any solution.

**Below JSON needs to be converted**:

```
[
    [
        {
            "FieldName": "Id",
            "Value": 1234
        },
        {
            "FieldName": "FieldName1",
            "Value": 2722
        },
        {
            "FieldName": "FieldName2",
            "Value": "2022-06-21T13:03:11.5958542Z"
        },
        {
            "FieldName": "FieldName3",
            "Value": "XYZ"
        }
    ]
]
```

**Required JSON structure from above JSON**:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1234,
        "FieldName1" : 2722,
        "FieldName2" : "2022-06-21T13:03:11.5958542Z",
        "FieldName3" : "XYZ"
    }
]
```

Comment: What did you try already? Can you share your current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over your inner array.

A single `JObject` has to be created and in the loop filled with the data from your input array.

The data type of the value has to be checked: `int.TryParse`
In the case of boolean values, the if condition has to be extended.

```cs
public void Transform()
{
    var data = "[ [ { \"FieldName\": \"Id\", \"Value\": 1234 }, { \"FieldName\": \"FieldName1\", \"Value\": 2722 }, { \"FieldName\": \"FieldName2\", \"Value\": \"2022-06-21T13:03:11.5958542Z\" }, { \"FieldName\": \"FieldName3\", \"Value\": \"XYZ\" } ] ]";

    var input = JArray.Parse(data);
    var inputFirst = input[0] as JArray;

    var outputItem = new JObject();

    foreach (JObject item in inputFirst)
    {
        var fieldName = item["FieldName"].Value<string>();
        var fieldValue = item["Value"].Value<string>();

        if (int.TryParse(fieldValue, out int fieldIntValue))
        {
            outputItem[fieldName] = fieldIntValue;
        }
        else
        {
            outputItem[fieldName] = fieldValue;
        }
    }

    var output = new JArray();
    output.Add(outputItem);

    var result = output.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

`Console.WriteLine(result);` writes following JSON:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": 1234,
    "FieldName1": 2722,
    "FieldName2": "06/21/2022 13:03:11",
    "FieldName3": "XYZ"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, @Markus explained the concept of how to transform from the input to output.

This solution is worked with **System.Linq** and able to transform to multiple objects.

In case your data is:

```
[
  [ {...}, {...}, ... ], // Array 1
  [ ], // Array 2
  ...
]
```

1. Transform to `JArray`.
2. Iterate the (first-level) array item(s).
3. Iterate (second-level) array item(s) and add the item to become a dictionary.

```cs
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var result = JArray.Parse(json)
            .Select(x => 
            {
                Dictionary<string, dynamic> dict = new ();

                foreach (JObject jObj in x.ToObject<List<JObject>>())
                {
                    dict.Add(jObj["FieldName"].ToString(), Int32.TryParse(jObj["Value"].ToString(), out int @value) ? @value : jObj["Value"].ToString());    
                }

                return dict;
            })
            .ToList();
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/76x0PE)